# Java streams list processing order

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Can someone please explain the output of below java streams code:

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(0);
l.add(1);
l.add(2);
l.add(3);
l.add(4);
l.add(4);
l.stream()
    .distinct()
    .map(v -> {
        System.out.println("In Map " + v);
        return v;
    }).forEach(v -> {
        System.out.println("In ForEach " + v);
    });
```

I expected:

```
In Map 0 
    In Map 1 
    In Map 2 
    In Map 3 
    In Map 4 
    In ForEach 0 
    In ForEach 1 
    In ForEach 2 
    In ForEach 3 
    In ForEach 4
```

But it prints:

```
In Map 0 
    In ForEach 0 
    In Map 1 
    In ForEach 1 
    In Map 2 
    In ForEach 2 
    In Map 3 
    In ForEach 3 
    In Map 4 
    In ForEach 4
```

Comment: Any reason why you expected it to be like that?

Comment: Streams are *lazy*, one element at a time is pulled from the source, what you see is expected. I am 100% sure this is a duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is pretty obvious :) It goes in Map and for each value does the foreach call. It's like nested loops. Get value 1 - process it, get value 2 process it ;) And that's what you get

Answer (score 0):

The `Stream` pipeline is lazily evaluated. Meaning it performs intermediate operations on `Stream` elements only when such elements are required by the terminal operation - `forEach` in your case.

If the terminal operation required only a single element (for example `findFirst()`), the `map()` operation would be executed only for the first element of the `Stream`.